# Basic parallel array with two Strings

Tags: java

When I test it, it builds fine. But when I run it only the intro and user output questions come up (which is what it's supposed to do), but when I input an answer an error comes up:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 50
    at statecapitals.StateCapitals.main(StateCapitals.java:141)
```

Now I know i'm new at this but what I think the error is, is that my arrays are not corresponding and i'm not sure what I did wrong. Any help would much appreciated. Here is what I have:

```
    String[] stateName = new String[50];
    String[] capName = new String[50];

    int i;
    for(i=0; i < 50; i++)
    {
    stateName[0] = "Alabama";
    stateName[1] = "Alaska";
    .....
    capName[0] = "Montgomery";
    capName[1] = "Juneau";
    .....
    }

    boolean found = false;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("This program is designed...");
    System.out.println("Please enter the name of a U.S. state (please enter capitalized):");
    stateName[i] = keyboard.nextLine();

    for(i=0; (!found) && (i < stateName.lenth); i++)
      if(stateName[i].matches(capName[i]) )
      System.out.print(The capital of " + stateName + " is " + capName);
      found = true;
        if(!found)
        System.out.println("The name you entered was not on the list.");
```

*Updated & edited:
the line of code that was having the most trouble was:

```
    stateName[i] = keyboard.nextLine();
```

Thank you for everyone's help, i've made some changes:

```
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < 49; i++)
    {
    stateName[i+1]
    .....
    capName[i+1]
    ...
    }
```

Plus I added the curly brackets to my for loop at the bottom. Now when I run it, it stops on the line:

```
    if(capName[i].matches(stateName[i]) )
```

and the error this time is:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at statecapitals.StateCapitals.main(StateCapitals.java:146)
```

Thank you again for everyone's input.

Comment: I can't tell the problem from the above code. Which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: Hint: on line 141 you try to access array index 50 when the length of the array is less than 50.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be your real code -- there are typos that would prevent it from compiling.

Comment: This code does not compile (`i < stateName.lenth` ?). If you did something like `stateName[i+1] = "Alaska";` then it is normal, `i+1` becomes `50` when `i = 49` => Out of bounds.

Comment: Tip : Are you aware that you ALWAYS reach `found = true` in your for loop? Please avoid statements without curly brackets.

Comment: "my arrays are not corresponding"  ... that's why you should try to avoid using parallel arrays.

Comment: 2nd tip : you ALWAYS break the `for loop` at `found = true` because this loop also does not have curly brackets.

Comment: Use a `Map<String, String>` or even better a `State` object that holds both values.

Answer (score 1):

Since `i` is not initizalized (in the snippet)

```
stateName[i] = keyboard.nextLine();
```

should be something like:

```
searchState = keyboard.nextLine();
```

And this comparison is pointless since it would never match (should be searchState  from above):

```
 if(stateName[i].matches(capName[i]) )
```

Comment: Yes - fundamental issue with overwriting the answer key with the value input... You are on to something here!

Answer (score 0):

problem 1

```
 stateName[i] = keyboard.nextLine();
```

problem 2

```
 for(i=0; i < 50; i++)
{
stateName[0] = "Alabama";
stateName[1] = "Alaska";
.....
capName[0] = "Montgomery";
capName[1] = "Juneau";
.....
}
```

i think this should be stateName[i] = "Alabama";

Problem 3

You missed the `"{" "}"` in the for loop

```
for(i=0; (!found) && (i < stateName.length); i++){

      if(stateName[i].matches(capName[i]) ){
          System.out.print(The capital of " + stateName + " is " + capName);
          found = true;
      }            
}
if(!found)
   System.out.println("The name you entered was not on the list.");
```

Comment: That's right, but I don't think that it's the reason for the exception.

Comment: I think that the `if` statement should also have curly brackets and that `found = true` should be included in it.

Answer (score 0):

You've had a lot of good suggestions to improve your code that I would try to implement.

The reason for the error is your for loop.

```
for(i=0; (!found) && (i < stateName.lenth); i++)
```

The length of the array is going to return 50, but your indexes go from 0 - 49 and because you never find a match, it goes through the whole loop.